# my send mail not found in inbox

Tags: asp.net

i want to send mail in asp.net form here is my coding

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("192.168.1.2",Convert.ToInt32 (25));
  System.Net.NetworkCredential cre = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
  smtp.Credentials = cre;
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
  message.To.Add(new MailAddress("uamrit@gmail.com"));
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;
  message.Body = "<html><head><body><p> this is Demo for sending mail. </p></body></head></html>";
  message.Subject=("response from the web sitre");
  message.From = new MailAddress("uamrit@gmail.com");

  try
  {
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Send(message);
    Response.Write("Your Email has been sent sucessfully -");
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    Response.Write("Send failure: " + exc.ToString());
  }
}
```

in web.config

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp from="uamrit@gmail.com">
   <network host="192.168.1.299" port="25" userName="uamrit" password="*****"/>
  </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

this show mail send successfully but when we check my gmail account there no one mail for me why this happen.
what the procedure to send mail
plz send me full coding

Comment: Obvious question: Is it in your spam folder?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons.Did you check your SPAM inbox? Also I see that you are pretending to send an email from GMAIL account through another server and I am sure GMAIL will not like it and migh blacklist your email address.

If you are planning to use GMAIL then why not use GMAIL [SMTP settings](http://techblissonline.com/gmail-smtp/)?

Answer (score 0):

In your config, you define a user name and password - yet, in your code, you specify

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

You need to decide which one to use - default credentials, or the username/password in the config?

I would think if you define a username/password in your config, you don't want to override that in your code by specifying `UseDefaultCredentials = true...`

If that doesn't solve you problems, I would try to specify the SMTP mail to go to a directory of your choosing, and see if the mails (stored as `*.eml` files in that directory) are really created at all. To do so, use this config:

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp from="uamrit@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="specifiedPickupDirectory">
     <specifiedPickupDirectory>C:\temp\mails</specifiedPickupDirectory>
  </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

You need to make sure the directory defined does already exist, though!